# fopen hidden files in c language

Tags: c, linux, fopen

I am using ubuntu linux and i am just a beginner is c language i have created a program that creates a lock file when started inside a folder but both the file and folder are with [DOT] like .folder and .file and linux hides such files and folders and i have another program that checks if the file exists or not if it exists then the program is running and if it doesn't then its not simple here is my code

```
FILE* lockfile = fopen("/.folder/.lock", "r");
if (!lockfile) {
    printf("Cannot find lock file");
} else {
    printf("lock file found");
}
```

the folder is in the root directory and i just wanna read the file so i gave "r" as the access i made a lot of search but only found answers to windows based programs can anyone point out where am i wrong or any solution for it?
how can i read hidden files and folders in linux through c?

EDIT: added images to make things a bit more clear

[image: folder]

The `.folder` directory it has all the permission for the current user

[image: file]

The `.lock` file also has the read permission for the current user so i don't think there is a problem with the permission or i am still wrong?

Comment: `fopen` has no problem opening filenames beginning with a dot.

Comment: please run `ls -al /.folder/.lock`.  I imagine the permissions are not what you think.

Comment: @cnicutar - I don't know but it always says cannot find lock file just the thing is i really don't understand what's wrong with it
@djechlin - if i run that command in a terminal like `ls -al /.folder` then it displays the .lock file but i never knew you can run commands in `fopen` also

Comment: Your code says `/.folder/.lock` (the filesystem root `/`) but your screenshot is showing your home directory (`~/`, `/home/keshav`) ? Your user doesn't have the rights in `/`.

Comment: Change `printf("Cannot find lock file");`  to `perror( "/.folder/.lock" );`  (or, preferrably, to `char *path = ".directory/.lock"; lockfil = fopen( path, "r"); ... perror( path );`

Comment: Your looking in the root directory for the lock file, yet it's in your home folder (`/home/username` on most Linuxes). Try `~/.folder/.lock`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no such thing as a "hidden" file in *nix. The leading dot is a convention followed by tools to inhibit their display, but there is no difference between them and any other filesystem object of the same type in the system.

Comment: so why can't it read the file is it because the file and folder is in root directory?

Comment: It's because you don't have sufficient permissions to read it.

Comment: you mean as a user right

Comment: As the user or group that owns the process.

Comment: i have edited the question both the file and folder are having read permission to the current user

Comment: Uh... you realize that `~/` is not `/`, right?

Comment: ya i changed the path to `/home/keshav/.folder` and it works but the `~/` has no effect on it

Answer (score 4):

```
i just wanna read the file so i gave "r" as the access
```

Here's the issue. If you have *only* read (`r`) access to a folder, you can only list out (`ls`) the contents of it, not read or write to any files inside that folder. This is the reason `fopen` fails.

You should also give execute(`x`) permission to that directory if you want to read a file inside it. So the directory will have both read & execute permissions (`r` and `x`).

Comment: I reread your answer and I see what I misread the first time. Execute permission *itself* is not sufficient to read files within a directory. If you change your last sentence to read "You should give read *and* execute (`rx`) permission" then I think that will resolve the confusion.

Comment: @KingsIndian -  I tried it but still doesn't work when i looked at the file from the location i can't see it but if i use `ls -la /.folder` then it displays all the files including `.lock` file

Comment: @KingsIndian - no still no luck does the access in fopen change the user permissions also? i mean i am not logged in as root is that the problem?

Comment: @GregHewgill I see, just edited to clarify it a bit more. Thanks.

Comment: @KeshavNair Just give the permissions to both the file as well as the directory. Run the following and try fopen again: `chmod 555 /.folder` and `chmod 777 /.folder/.lock` 777 is everything for everyone. You can change if you wish.

Comment: @KingsIndian - again a problem i can't allow anyone to access the folder or the file as it contains some sensitive data that is sent and received to my server

Comment: @KeshavNair You can just change it as per your needs. For example, if you want to give permissions only for the owner then 500 & 700 instead of 555 & 777 would do. Does fopen work now?

Comment: @KeshavNair Your directory `.folder` is in `home` directory. Either create a directory in `/` Or change the path in `fopen` accordingly.

Comment: ok i changed the path and it works